# React <Switch> ProtectedRoute problem / doesn't work as expected

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am making React application with some protected routes. 
It works fine till I'm adding Switch wrapper, then /about and /contact routes couldn't be displayed.

Could you explain why it's happening? And if Switch here is necessary?

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, path, rootModel }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      exact
      path={path}
      render={(props) => {
        loginCheck();
        return (
          <>
            {rootModel.auth.isLoggedIn ? (
              <Component {...props} rootModel={rootModel} />
            ) : (
              <Redirect to='/login' />
            )}
          </>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};

const Routes = ({ rootModel }) => {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/login' component={Login} />

        <PrivateRoute path='/' component={Main} rootModel={rootModel} />
        <PrivateRoute path='/about' component={About} rootModel={rootModel} />
        <PrivateRoute path='/about' component={About} rootModel={rootModel} />
        <PrivateRoute
          path='/contact'
          component={Contact}
          rootModel={rootModel}
        />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make that login check before you return nothing just like this:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, path, rootModel }) => {
  const isLogged = loginCheck();
  if (rootModel.auth.isLoggedIn) {
      return (
    <Route
      exact
      path={path}
      render={(props) => {
        loginCheck();
        return (
              <Component {...props} rootModel={rootModel} />
            )}
          </>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
  } else {
       return <Redirect to={} />
  }

};
```

Comment: Could you provide loginCheck code? I'm pretty sure we will sort it out!

Comment: It's just an api call which looks if user is logged in. Anyway when I deleted thisnline the problem persisted.